# Как сделать с помощью Python библиотеки Telebot чтобы к отправленной рандомной фотографии был привязан соответствующий текст?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telebot

Есть функция при которой из списка в рандомном порядке выбирается фоторафия и отправляется, но к ней должен быть привязан текст подоходящий именно к картинке, как это реализовать?

```
elif message.text.strip() == 'Філософ':
    bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, open(random.choice(photo), 'rb'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно где-то хранить данные зависимости, например в БД `MySQL` или любой другой, исходя из ваших предпочтений.

---

Структура таблицы будет следующей:

| id | photo | text |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | **%путь_к_фото_1%** | **%текст_для_фото_1%** |
| 2 | **%путь_к_фото_2%** | **%текст_для_фото_2%** |

`photo` - путь до изображения.

`text` - подпись к изображению.

---

**UPDATE.** Для подключения к `MySQL` потребуется библиотека `PyMySQL`, установить ее можно с помощью команды `pip install PyMySQL`.

```
import pymysql
from random import randint


def connect_to_db(): 
   con = pymysql.connect('localhost', 'user', 
                         'password', 'database')
   cur = con.cursor()
   return con, cur


def get_random_id(cur):
   cur.execute("SELECT MAX(id) FROM photo_text")
   max_id = cur.fetchone()
   return randint(1, max_id[0])

def get_random_photo_text():
   con, cur = connect_to_db()
   rand_id = get_random_id(cur)
   cur.execute("SELECT photo, text FROM photo_text WHERE id=" + str(rand_id))
   data = cur.fetchone()
   cur.close()
   con.close()
   return data[0], data[1] #data[0] - путь к фото, data[1] - подпись
```

Comment: Как правильно реализовать функцию в python?

Comment: @Eyex какую именно функцию?

Comment: @mazik2512 функция которая будет отправлять на запрос одновременно фото и текст в рандомном порядке. Вот-с на мета языке: если бот получает запрос то сделать ответ используя функцию отправки рандомного фото с текстом которые привязанные в mysql к id...Можете подсказать как это сделать на синтаксисе python?

Comment: @Eyex обновил ответ.

Comment: @Eyex Если ответ вам подошел, его нужно принять (галочка слева от ответа).